# Android Studio „cannot resolve symbol” for any import that had „android.” in the beginning

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 4.1.2 and today I tried to open a project that I've created some months ago, but the problem that occurs it's that all the imports that start with `android.`, are written with red, informing me that the IDE `cannot resolve symbol ..`.

An exemple of all imports with red are as follows:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

All the imports that starts with `androidx.` are working. All i've done it's installing the new version of `Android Studio` (I am currently working in `React`, so I didn't even have `AS` installed) and opening the project which some months ago was working properly.
What i've tried so far:

1. Clean the project, rebuild;
2. Invalidate caches + restart;
3. Deleting the `.idea`folder and restarting project;
4. Closing the project and re-importing it.

None of the above worked.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found the issue. As stated in the question, I've just installed the `Android Studio`, so the only `SDK` installed was for `API Level 30`, the last one, for `Android 11`. In my `build.graddle(app)` I had `compileSdkVersion 29` so, installing from `File > Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > Systems Settings > Android SDK` the `SDK` for `API Level 29` solved my issue and the `IDE` started working properly.